# Npm install fails for Phoenix LiveView app in Windows 10

Tags: npm, elixir, phoenix-framework, phoenix-live-view

### Background

I have a Phoenix app, in a fresh Windows 10 VM. In this project I cannot run `npm install` without errors.

### Problem

After running `npm install` inside the `assets` directory I get the following output:

```
λ npm install
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated svgo@1.3.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.
npm WARN deprecated tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please upgrade asap.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\User\Workplace\market_manager\apps\web_interface\assets\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\User\Workplace\market_manager\apps\web_interface\assets\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
npm ERR! Build started 11/11/2021 9:26:11 AM.
npm ERR! Project "C:\Users\User\Workplace\market_manager\apps\web_interface\assets\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.sln" on node 1 (default targets).
npm ERR! ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
npm ERR!   Building solution configuration "Release|x64".
npm ERR! Project "C:\Users\User\Workplace\market_manager\apps\web_interface\assets\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.sln" (1) is building "C:\Users\User\Workplace\market_manager\apps\web_interface\assets\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj.metaproj" (2) on node 1 (default targets).
npm ERR! Project "C:\Users\User\Workplace\market_manager\apps\web_interface\assets\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj.metaproj" (2) is building "C:\Users\User\Workplace\market_manager\apps\web_interface\assets\node_modules\node-sass\build\src\libsass.vcxproj" (3) on node 1 (default targets).
npm ERR! C:\Users\User\Workplace\market_manager\apps\web_interface\assets\node_modules\node-sass\build\src\libsass.vcxproj(20,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
npm ERR! Done Building Project "C:\Users\User\Workplace\market_manager\apps\web_interface\assets\node_modules\node-sass\build\src\libsass.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
npm ERR! Done Building Project "C:\Users\User\Workplace\market_manager\apps\web_interface\assets\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj.metaproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
npm ERR! Done Building Project "C:\Users\User\Workplace\market_manager\apps\web_interface\assets\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.sln" (default targets) -- FAILED.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Build FAILED.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! "C:\Users\User\Workplace\market_manager\apps\web_interface\assets\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.sln" (default target) (1) ->
npm ERR! "C:\Users\User\Workplace\market_manager\apps\web_interface\assets\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj.metaproj" (default target) (2) ->
npm ERR! "C:\Users\User\Workplace\market_manager\apps\web_interface\assets\node_modules\node-sass\build\src\libsass.vcxproj" (default target) (3) ->
npm ERR!   C:\Users\User\Workplace\market_manager\apps\web_interface\assets\node_modules\node-sass\build\src\libsass.vcxproj(20,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!     0 Warning(s)
npm ERR!     1 Error(s)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Time Elapsed 00:00:00.05
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Users\\User\\Workplace\\market_manager\\apps\\web_interface\\assets\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@17.0.1 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2.7" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2.7
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\User\Workplace\market_manager\apps\web_interface\assets\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\User\Workplace\market_manager\apps\web_interface\assets\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\User\Workplace\market_manager\apps\web_interface\assets\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\User\Workplace\market_manager\apps\web_interface\assets\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\User\Workplace\market_manager\apps\web_interface\assets\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\User\Workplace\market_manager\apps\web_interface\assets\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  python2.7 Error: not found: python2.7
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\User\Workplace\market_manager\apps\web_interface\assets\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\User\Workplace\market_manager\apps\web_interface\assets\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\User\Workplace\market_manager\apps\web_interface\assets\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\User\Workplace\market_manager\apps\web_interface\assets\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\User\Workplace\market_manager\apps\web_interface\assets\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\User\Workplace\market_manager\apps\web_interface\assets\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21) {
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed }
npm ERR! gyp verb could not find "python2.7". checking python launcher
npm ERR! gyp verb check python launcher python executable found: "C:\\Users\\User\\.windows-build-tools\\python27\\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp verb check python version `C:\Users\User\.windows-build-tools\python27\python.exe -c "import sys; print "2.7.15
npm ERR! gyp verb check python version .%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];"` returned: %j
npm ERR! gyp verb get node dir no --target version specified, falling back to host node version: 17.0.1
npm ERR! gyp verb command install [ '17.0.1' ]
npm ERR! gyp verb install input version string "17.0.1"
npm ERR! gyp verb install installing version: 17.0.1
npm ERR! gyp verb install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already installed
npm ERR! gyp verb install version is already installed, need to check "installVersion"
npm ERR! gyp verb got "installVersion" 9
npm ERR! gyp verb needs "installVersion" 9
npm ERR! gyp verb install version is good
npm ERR! gyp verb get node dir target node version installed: 17.0.1
npm ERR! gyp verb build dir attempting to create "build" dir: C:\Users\User\Workplace\market_manager\apps\web_interface\assets\node_modules\node-sass\build
npm ERR! gyp verb build dir "build" dir needed to be created? C:\Users\User\Workplace\market_manager\apps\web_interface\assets\node_modules\node-sass\build
npm ERR! gyp verb build/config.gypi creating config file
npm ERR! gyp verb build/config.gypi writing out config file: C:\Users\User\Workplace\market_manager\apps\web_interface\assets\node_modules\node-sass\build\config.gypi
npm ERR! (node:7852) [DEP0150] DeprecationWarning: Setting process.config is deprecated. In the future the property will be read-only.
npm ERR! (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
npm ERR! gyp verb config.gypi checking for gypi file: C:\Users\User\Workplace\market_manager\apps\web_interface\assets\node_modules\node-sass\config.gypi
npm ERR! gyp verb common.gypi checking for gypi file: C:\Users\User\Workplace\market_manager\apps\web_interface\assets\node_modules\node-sass\common.gypi
npm ERR! gyp verb gyp gyp format was not specified; forcing "msvs"
npm ERR! gyp info spawn C:\Users\User\.windows-build-tools\python27\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\User\\Workplace\\market_manager\\apps\\web_interface\\assets\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\gyp\\gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'msvs',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-G',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'msvs_version=2015',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\User\\Workplace\\market_manager\\apps\\web_interface\\assets\\node_modules\\node-sass\\build\\config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\User\\Workplace\\market_manager\\apps\\web_interface\\assets\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\User\\.node-gyp\\17.0.1\\include\\node\\common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=C:\\Users\\User\\.node-gyp\\17.0.1',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=C:\\Users\\User\\Workplace\\market_manager\\apps\\web_interface\\assets\\node_modules\\node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=C:\\Users\\User\\.node-gyp\\17.0.1\\<(target_arch)\\node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=C:\\Users\\User\\Workplace\\market_manager\\apps\\web_interface\\assets\\node_modules\\node-sass',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\User\\Workplace\\market_manager\\apps\\web_interface\\assets\\node_modules\\node-sass\\build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp verb command build []
npm ERR! gyp verb build type Release
npm ERR! gyp verb architecture x64
npm ERR! gyp verb node dev dir C:\Users\User\.node-gyp\17.0.1
npm ERR! gyp verb found first Solution file build/binding.sln
npm ERR! gyp verb could not find "msbuild.exe" in PATH - finding location in registry
npm ERR! gyp info spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build/binding.sln',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/nologo',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Users\User\Workplace\market_manager\apps\web_interface\assets\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:262:23)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19043
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\User\\Workplace\\market_manager\\apps\\web_interface\\assets\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\User\Workplace\market_manager\apps\web_interface\assets\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v17.0.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-11-11T17_26_17_515Z-debug.log
```

I am using Node v17.0.1, the latest version with all the dependencies installed.

### What I have tried

My first reaction was to downgrade Node to the LTS, in this case v16.X. (a fine reminder from the past:
https://elixirforum.com/t/npm-installation-for-fresh-phoenixliveview-project-failing-in-windows-10/37170
)
However that didn't work either.

Then I tried to manually download the VSCode tools dependencies manually and to setup everything manually. That was also a dead end.

I am running all the command in a shell with Admin privileges.

At this point I don't know what else to try.

### Question

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying for several weeks I eventually gave up.
The best way to avoid this error is simply to install Phoenix's newest version:
https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/installation.html

Which does not use SASS and therefore wont need NodeJS to compile.

I ended up creating a fresh project and porting my old code there. Not the best experience.